# How can I unlock my Samsung Galaxy Note 3 without factory reset

Tags: samsung, password, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I suddenly cannot access my phone with my normal password. it just keeps saying its incorrect. How can I unlock my Samsung Galaxy Note 3 without factory reset. Very urgent help needed please.

Comment: Don't you get an option to use your Google account to log in after 10 or so tried to enter the password?

Comment: No there is no such option. I have tried it keeps saying you have typed the wrong password 10 or 15 times, try again in 30 seconds.

Comment: Pat, you should have mentioned that the points mentioned in the answer don't work for you before posting. Please do so in the future as it helps to prevent us from posting useless (for you, that is) information.

Comment: Sorry about that. Any other helpful tips please?

Comment: Yeah. Please go through this: http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

**Follow the below steps if you forgot lock screen password.**

1. Enter a wrong lock screen pattern five times (shouldn’t be hard if
   you don’t remember the correct one)
2. Select ‘Forgot Pattern’
3. Now you should be able to enter a backup PIN or your Google account
   login.
4. Enter either your backup PIN or your Google login.
5. Your phone should now be unlocked.

**You can also follow Device Manager by Android steps**

*Ensure that you had enabled Android Device Manager as a device administrator under security settings before trying this.*

1. On a computer or other mobile phone, visit:
   google.com/android/devicemanager
2. Sign in using your Google login details that you also used on your
   locked phone.
3. In the ADM interface, select the device you need to unlock (if it
   isn’t already selected).
4. Select ‘Lock’
5. In the appearing window, enter a temporary password. You don’t have
    to enter a recovery message. Now click ‘Lock’ again.
6. If it was successful, you should see a confirmation below the box
    with the buttons Ring, Lock and Erase.
7. On your phone you should now see a password field in which you
    should enter the temporary password. This should unlock your phone.
8. Now, before you go on with your life, go to your phone’s lock
    screen settings and disable the temporary password.

**Disable your lock screen using custom recovery and “Pattern Password Disable”**

1. Download the [pattern password disable](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2532214&d=1390399283) ZIP file on your computer and
    put it on an SD card.
2. Insert the SD card into your phone.
3. Reboot your phone into recovery.
4. Flash the ZIP file on your SD card.
5. Reboot.

Your phone should boot up without a locked screen. Should there be a password or gesture lock screen, don’t panic. Just type in a random password or gesture and your phone should unlock

That’s it!

Comment: Thanks for the response but I've tried all these before posting my question and it still didn't work. The device manager keeps saying device is offline or network is unstable. but my device is online with pretty stable network,

Comment: Also, please ask for clarification or comment on the OP's question as comments, not as part of the answer

Comment: Try to reconnect with network again and try. If this not works you may go for erase all details.  You need to move on to more drastic measures. In case Android Device Manager is enabled on your phone and unlocking it didn’t work, you can use it to erase all data by selecting the Erase button. Be aware that this will delete all apps, settings and other data on your phone. The good thing is, once the erasing process is done, you can use your phone again (after setting everything up).

Comment: Erasing my data isn't an option right now. I have a lot of info on my phone that I cant afford to lose.

Comment: Have u tried Samsung's "Find My Mobile tool"?.This is an easy way to unlock your Samsung device if you created a Samsung account and registered it beforehand.

Comment: Yes but its not working either.trying to contact the samsung website now

Comment: ok then if you know rooting and custom recovery you may try this "Disable your lock screen using custom recovery and “Pattern Password Disable” zip file. If your ok with it i'll edit my answer with this method

Comment: I do not have an idea how to do this can you put me through please

Comment: Edited my answer with third method. Please don't try if you don't know root and custom recovery.

Comment: I do not know root and custom recovery. Thanks for all ur help

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and to me it was weird! It happened like this:

My Note 3 hot spot (tethering) stopped working. When I switched it on it displayed a message "hot spot in use" and it did not connect to any of my devices as usual.

I reinstalled my device (reset to factory settings) and it worked perfectly. Hot sport stared working. Then I set my common password to my Note 3, and actually I used it for a couple of times. Later, the devices rejected my password! All the time it said "wrong password"!

I used several options including locking it using "Android Device Manager" exactly as the method is suggested here above. Yes, my phone was locked with a black screen but it did not REPLACE the lock screen with one I put in the website for Android device manager! (I think this is not good. Android device manager should be more serious) So I was stuck again!

What I finally did was to go to the "https://account.samsung.com" and put my Samsung account information and used the "unlock" button. All passwords were wiped clean! Now I can access my devise.

I hope this will help somebody

Frank P. Seth

Answer (score -1):

The other two answers are good, this is just another system/recovery way of backing up your data in case you don't have access to a backup PIN or Google Account. But of course, you'll need to have access to fastboot and CWM recovery image of your device for this to work!

1. Start your phone in fastboot mode by long-pressing DnVolume+Power button.
2. Connect to a PC using USB cable (ensure ADB drivers are installed) and run this command (replace path with your CWM image path):

   ```
   fastboot boot /path/to/CWM.img
   ```
3. Once inside CWM recovery you can use adb commands! Mount the /data and /system partitions if they aren't already, and pull whatever data you want. For example, to list all the files and folders in your external sdcard, run:

   ```
   adb shell ls -al /sdcard/
   ```
4. To copy a file, run:

   ```
   adb pull /sdcard/foo.bar
   ```

This way, you can recover anything you want from the phone/tablet even if you forgot your PIN and don't have access to internet or google account or an OEM alternative method!

Comment: requires unlocked bootloader, and fastboot is not available for samsung devices